# Extending an xarray Dataset

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am trying to add a count of frost days to the xarray tutorial dataset.

```
airtemps = xr.tutorial.load_dataset('air_temperature')
# The set spans more than a year, let's take only one
airtemps = airtemps.sel(time=slice('2013-01-01', '2013-12-31'))
airtemps['air'] = airtemps.air - 273.15
```

The data is pretty high-resolution time-wise so for easier handling I resample them
    air_day   = airtemps.resample('1D', 'time', how='mean')
    air_month = air_day.resample('1M', 'time', how='mean')

As I result, I'd like to have an additional variable in `air_month` with a count of the days with averages below zero, along all three dimensions.

My very naiv attempt would be sth. like this

```
air_month['frost'] = sum(air_day.air < 0)
```

However by `sum()`ing, I loose the time dimension here. I am stuck here, still haven't wrapped the xarray concepts around my head.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Not sure whether this *the* way to do it, but it seems to work:
`air_day['frost'] = air_day.air < 0`

`air_day.frost.groupby('time.month').sum('time').plot(col='month', col_wrap=3)`

Comment: How would you extend the data forwards in time? So if you wanted to copy `airtemps.sel(time=0)` forwards in time using the date-range `pd.data_range('2013-01-01', '2013-12-31'))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there! 
And your groupby is very similar (and in some ways nicer given xarray's resample isn't yet a groupby)

```
In [24]: (air_day.air < 0).resample('M', dim='time', how='sum')
Out[24]:
<xarray.DataArray 'air' (time: 12, lat: 25, lon: 53)>
array([[[31, 31, 31, ..., 31, 31, 31],
        [31, 31, 31, ..., 31, 31, 31],
        [31, 31, 31, ..., 31, 31, 31],
        ...,
        [ 0,  0,  0, ...,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0, ...,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0, ...,  0,  0,  0]]])
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float32 75.0 72.5 70.0 67.5 65.0 62.5 60.0 57.5 55.0 52.5 ...
  * lon      (lon) float32 200.0 202.5 205.0 207.5 210.0 212.5 215.0 217.5 ...
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2013-01-31 2013-02-28 2013-03-31 ...
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! This is what I imagined it should look like!